# Pion decay into electron and anti-neutrino

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

In Peskin and Schroeder Books Chapter 5 subsubection Bound State equation (5.43)

$\mathcal{M}(\uparrow \uparrow \rightarrow B)=\sqrt{2M}\int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}\tilde{\psi^\ast}(\mathbf{k})\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}\mathcal{M}(\uparrow \uparrow \rightarrow \mathbf{k} \uparrow, - \mathbf{k}\uparrow)$

My question :
If i would like to calculate the decay width of pion decay, can anybody tell me how to use that equation.

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up eq43 with eq44, you should replace $\left|B\right\rangle$ with $\mathcal{M}(\uparrow\uparrow\rightarrow B)$

But in any case, in the derivation of this expression an important assumption has been made, one which does not hold for pions!

The bound state must be non relativistic to a good approximation. This is true for heavy quark mesons, not for light quark mesons like the pion which is an intrinsically relativistic system (a good way to quickly understand why is to compare the binding energy with the rest energy of the constituents)

Comment: thank you, I have edited my questions. Pion is composed by down quark and anti-up quark. So, because Pion is relativistic can I assume that down quark and anti-up quark as individual particle (not forming a bound state)? Then I use feynman diagram rules just like another case.

Comment: No they are still a bound state, but because they are relativistic you cannot use the non-relativistic schrodinger wave function description to represent them as in the given equation... So you need the full nonperturbative QFT apparatus

Comment: So, you mean that for example we should use [Bethe-Salpeter equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethe%E2%80%93Salpeter_equation) to solve this problem? Or is there another solution?

Comment: Except that the Bethe-Saltpeter equation can only be solved for relatively non relativistic systems...

Comment: Because QCD is strongly coupled for low energies, to calculate the pion decay rate from quark interactions you need to know the non-perturbative spectrum of QCD which nobody knows

Comment: The only thing we can know analytically about pion decay rate is some relations due to considering the pion as a goldsote boson.. see for example Goldberger-Treiman relation

Comment: In Halzen and Martin Section Weak Interaction subsection Pion Decay page 264, there is some procedure to calculate Pion Decay Width. Is this the example of Goldberger-Treiman relation?
Sorry, I do not study QCD and newbie in QFT.

Comment: @Ali Moh This statement is not completely true: "(...)  you need to know the non-perturbative spectrum of QCD which nobody knows". Nobody knows how to obtain analytic expressions from QCD (at low energies)! 

But in the last decades, we have developed some numerical tools that allow us to study simple processes like this one. The idea is to use Lorentz and parity symmetry to express the matrix element in terms of functions (decay constants or form factors) that will be computed by numerical simulations on the Lattice.

Comment: In particular, the leptonic decay of pions depends only on one constant that we call $f_\pi$, which is very precisely determined by lattice simulations. 

Nowadays, we are so confident about lattice simulations that we are even using similar channels (like $B \to \tau \nu$) to look for New Physics (eg. charged scalars).

You can find some interesting comments here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/116499/how-do-we-measure-meson-decay-constants

Comment: True, I was excluding numerical techniques from my conclusions. In principle $f_\pi$ should be calculable only from the QCD lagrangian, which even though not done analytically, could be (and is as you say) calculated using lattice-QCD simulations.

Comment: @Panuluh regarding p 264, you can see there that in the paradigm of effective field theory we write down the pion muon neutrino vertex based on known symmetries, combining all our (analytic) ignorance about the microscopic theory description of pion decay in one constant $f_\pi$. Then this is totally unknown, except you can estimate it using dimensional analysis (or precisely using the lattice as Melquiades noted). Then he goes on to calculate ratios which is the only thing you can predict, by canceling $f_\pi$